# How to save file in detectron2

Tags: file, variables

When I use the cv2_imshow code of my custom dataset, I can view the results of detections on the image via Google Colaboratory. Now, I want to save this image to Google Drive.

```
v = Visualizer(im[:, :, ::-1], metadata=microcontroller_metadata, scale=1.2)
v = v.draw_instance_predictions(outputs["instances"].to("cpu"))
cv2_imshow(v.get_image()[:, :, ::-1])
```

However, when I use the demo.py code provided by detectron2, I get results with kites and other classes which are COCO classes but not my custom classes
I use this code to run demo.py

```
!python demo.py --config-file detectron2/configs/COCO-Detection/faster_rcnn_R_101_FPN_3x.yaml --input gdcnn/0_img_input/validate/validate{a}.jpg --confidence-threshold 0.2 --output path/to/googledrive/predictionfasterrcnn.jpg --opts MODEL.WEIGHTS output/model_final.pth
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save file like this:

```
v.save(filepath)
```

or

```
cv2.imwrite(filepath, v.get_image()[:, :, ::-1])
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Save the output file by using cv2 function to save image or instead use:

```
cv2.imwrite(filename, img)
```